# Booting elementary OS Freya from CD

Tags: system-installation

Some time ago I installed Ubuntu on my old laptop. How can Install elementary OS Freya from CD on Ubuntu? I tried booting, changing bios settings to boot CD first but it won't work.

This is what happens when I boot it:

http://benyouhuifile.it168.com/forum/201309/20/0154295o6vffvvo5zfq2p5.jpg

and then it just goes to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling network boot partition in your bios.

Then select cd-rom from the multi-boot option of you bios(generally f12).